# How to search on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Well it seems trivial but it is not.For example,I want to find videos about spectral leakage.But just writing down spectral leakage,leads to a lot of a content which have different content,for example spectral windows,leakage not related to this.Is there any other way for searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrow your search down - when you search something, there's a button above your first search result that says 'filter' - there's a vast amount of options in there that may help you find what you're looking for. I recommend you sort by 'relevance'

Hope this helps.

Sohail